# Matching linked data in Excel in one column to another when columns are not equal

Tags: excel-formula, matching

I apologize if this question has been asked before, but I have searched and cannot locate it.

Each cell in column B contains a specific (but not necessarily unique) value for each value in Column A. Column C contains all Column A cell data, but also contains additional data cells. I am attempting to create a new Column (D) for the Column B values to correspond with the Column A/B relationship. There will obviously be blank cells in Column D (for the rows where Column C contains data not located in Column A), but this is not an issue for me in this situation. Essentially, I want the A/B relationships to all be reflected in Columns C/D with blanks in the D rows where C has data not located in A.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell D1, do :

=iferror(index(b:b, match(c1, a:a, 0)),"")

Then drag downwards.

Idea/reference : I use index match function (a web search will explain it much better) to retrieve the column b value n fill it in column d. And put a blank "" if no match found. Pls share if it works/not.